# How to increase power in a geared system using P = (omega)(torque)

Tags: velocity, torque, power, angular-velocity

Could someone give me a basic, intuitive explanation on how to increase power in a geared system using the P = omega*torque formula?  By geared system I mean two connected gears, where the first one is powered by a motor, and by moving it turns the other.

Does it help if the two gears are smaller?  How does the distance from their centers affect things?  I'm a beginner at this, so just a basic explanation would help.

Comment: Power is not changed by the gear ratio, except for the losses in the system.

Comment: As DJohnM said, power is not increased. But torque can be increased or decreased, along with a change in speed.

Comment: @zeta-band  If P is constant in P = (omega)(torque), then is it better to make angular velocity (omega) smaller so that torque is greater?  Could this be done by making the first gear (the one powered by the motor) bigger so that it moves slower?

Comment: @InertialIgnorance If you want to increase the output torque, you make the gear connected to the motor be smaller than the one connected to the output shaft. The output shaft will turn slower, but with more torque. Suppose the gear connected to the motor has 6 teeth and the gear connected to the output shaft has 30 teeth. Then the output shaft will turn at 1/5 the speed, but with 5 times the torque.

Comment: @zeta-band Great, makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.